# send mail with PHP received some unwanted values

Tags: php, email

i have simple form that get name and email and state from user and send it via email.

I received email , and my code work fine. my problem is when i fill the form every thing are fine, but when other customer fill the form i received some unwanted value like `5c198d7a093bc` in name. here is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSub'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $state=$_POST['state'];
    if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($state)){
        header("location: http://example.com");
    }
    $to='support@example.com';
    $subject='thanks for send us info.';
    $message="
    <p style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;' >name: <b>".$name."</b></p>
    <p style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;' >email: <b>".$email."</b></p>
    <p style='font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;' >state: <b>".$state."</b></p></p>";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$email." \r\n" .
    "Reply-To: ".$email." \r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    if(!mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        echo "error while sending email";
    }else{
        echo "message sent";
    }
}
```

and my form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="index-form">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="email" type="email" />
    <input name="state" type="text" />
    <input name="btnSub" type="submit" />
</form>
```

**EDIT:**
I added this part for email validation:

```
if (!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
    echo "<center>Invalid email</center>";
}else{
    echo "<center>Valid Email</center>";
}
```

Comment: Use proper library to send e-mails, don't compose headers by yourself, don't send e-mails via mail.

Comment: @emix, thanks for your comment , i use php mailer class, and i still have this issue too.

Comment: Maybe customer (really a bot) typed `5c198d7a093bc` into your inputs, and that's why you got email with such data?

Comment: @Volvox, thanks for your reply, but `$state' value was empty in email!, that's surprised me.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because the issue cannot be reproduced.  I recommend implementing some stronger validations on the input values before feeding them to your mail function.

Comment: @mickmackusa, good point, more validation. but when i fill this form , everything work fine!

Comment: You may withdraw your question.

Comment: @mickmackusa : o.O , it's my first time to see this kind of problem , and i only looking for some reasonable answer.

Comment: Volunteers are not meant to answer Off-topic questions.  You have received guidance.  I hope that is enough to get you developing in the right direction.  By removing your question, you will regain the lost rep from downvotes.

Comment: @StackUser `$state` will not be empty if I just insert a space ;)

Comment: @BenM, you right, but it is so weird name changes like this, and when i fill it work fine, but when other ppl send data, its changes.. :(